# How to avoid my original page is changed?

Tags: javascript

By using the following code failed to prevent the original page is changed (also opens the contents of the second).
I want my original page do not change.
Thanks in advance

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var a;
            function url(a)
            {
                u = a
                window.open(u);
                return u;
            }
        </script>
        <title>xxx</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="javascript:location.href=url('http://www.google.com')">Click
        Here</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you don’t want the current page to change – then _don’t_ assign a new value to `location.href` …

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you really need to go through a javascript function, use this:

```
<a href="javascript:url('http://www.google.com')">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also removed (return u;).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the current page content, then onclick of link use:

```
function openUrl(event,elem){
    var win = window.open(elem.href,"googleWindow","width=500,height=500");
    console.log(elem.href);
    return false;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h6t6uauc/)

Answer (score -1):

Can you not just use `target="_blank"` in the **a** element? Instead of using JavaScript.